# Equivalence at word level

Tags: word-usage, translation, business-language, transatlantic-differences

Is there a one-to-one relationship between word and meaning?

Comment: No, there is not. Meaning is to a large degree based on context.

Comment: @Cerberus is right as usual. "Meaning" is not a simple concept at all. [Not even _word_ is a simple concept](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/3kindsofword.jpg).

Comment: I think it's Off Topic General Reference that the precise (and often the *broad*) meanings of *all* words depend on context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are words with one-to-one meaning, not depending on the context, but not usually there is no. Words in English are known of having more than one meaning, thus heavily depending on the context.

As an example of one-to-one word, I think it could be "water", water is water, not depending on the context if not provided with adjectives.

Comment: Yes, another could be 'animal', which is always 'animal' not depending on the context.

Comment: "Water" is both a noun and a verb. Surely there are two meanings there? Or is that two different words? The question is unanswerable.